# AEM querybuider predicate for string array

Tags: metadata, aem, query-builder

Is there a way to search for the assets where a metadata property is of type String[] instead of String ?

I tried below, but I am sure this is not correct:

```
path=/path/to/my/folder
p.limit=-1
1_property=jcr:content/metadata/myMetadata
1_property.type=array
```

Comment: Are you trying to find assets where this property is an array instead of a string or do you want to find assets where the array contains a certain value? Would you please clarify.

Comment: I want the assets where this property is an array instead of a string. Not looking for any value(s), just the 'type' of the property.

Comment: I do not think this is doable with xpath, I would look at SQL2 instead.